# PostgreSQL: Is it possible to sort the part of the string has datetime

Tags: postgresql, sorting

I have the name of the column that contains the data sequence and datetime type as shown below:

> DATA01_0003_20210126135705.zip
> DATA01_0002_20210127135030.zip
> DATA01_0004_20210126142913.zip

I want ORDER BY according to datetime, then the sequence string, is it possible?

> DATA01_0002_20210127135030.zip
> DATA01_0004_20210126142913.zip
> DATA01_0003_20210126135705.zip

I tried the statement like below but it sort in sequence before datetime:
 `SELECT filename FROM tblData ORDER BY filename`

> DATA01_0002_20210127135030.zip
> DATA01_0003_20210126135705.zip
> DATA01_0004_20210126142913.zip

`SELECT filename FROM tblData ORDER BY filename DESC`

> DATA01_0004_20210126142913.zip
> DATA01_0003_20210126135705.zip
> DATA01_0002_20210127135030.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in postgresql you can sort by expression.

to sort by the file's timestamp, it is necessary to extract that from the string. based on your examples, i am going to guess that the text after the last `_` will have the date. if that assumption holds, then the following will sort by date

```
SELECT filename from tbldata
order by reverse(split_part(reverse(filename), '_', 1))
```

if the number of `_` is fixed, then the trick with two `reverse`s is unnecessary. you can instead `order by split_part(filename, '_', 3)`

Comment: Thank you so much, I will learn more about the statement you gave me!